# When is the next Moderator Election?

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

When is the next moderator election?

Was wondering according to https://math.stackexchange.com/election it is around may each year (at least since 2012)

and I want to get a https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/207/caucus badge

Comment: Usually there's an evaluation whether or not new moderators are needed before there is an election. I feel that due to the recent improvements of the review system, many flags are handled by the community and the workload of the moderators is alleviated. I'm not sure whether or not we really need more diamonds here at the moment. (Perhaps if one of the moderators considers stepping down that would be different.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't think that more moderators are needed given the community involvement in dealing with reviews, but I think the moderators themselves should be subject to review at least annually.

Comment: @T.Bongers: I agree, but diamonds are forever. So this sort of review is probably (and should be) internal to SE. In this case, I don't know how many complaints have been filed on the behavior of the moderators, something which may or may not prompt such a review process explicitly.

Comment: @Asaf: the word "forever" needs an asterisk.

Comment: @Willie: Well, we all know it, but someday the internet is going to disappear as we know it, and the information that is on the internet might not be preserved throughout the generations. Let's say at most $10^{80}$ years, just to be safe. :-)

Comment: @Willemien: well, I _could_ step down if it will help you get your badge. `:-)` @Asaf: judging by our friendly cast of current and past moderators, I would have estimated a much shorter half-life.

Comment: I, for one, am very happy with the current mod team and our workload, and I don't expect to have another election this year.

Comment: I am happy with our current moderators. I know that they have a difficult job and I don't expect perfect behavior. But as a matter os principle I would support term limits (say three years with elections every year (so not replace the whole team)). Maybe we just once a year have a confidence vote on the current moderators. If the moderators pass the vote, then we will not have elections. If a moderator doesn't pass the confidence vote (s)he losses his/her job and we have an election to replace that moderator. Again, I would suspect that the current moderators would all pass a confidence vote.

Comment: (cont.) Also, in all cases I would suggest that moderators should be able to run for reelection.

Comment: @Willie: I'm not disputing. I'd guess that $10^{\log_{10}(50)}$ years is probably a better upper limit. (I think that a drop from $10^{80}$ to $10^{\log_{10}(50)}$ deserves a publication. It's not every day we see such a dramatic improvements in the upper bounds of something!)

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I'm somewhat afraid of an election. The current mods seem to be getting along rather well (which does not mean that we always agree). We are also communicating with each other (and the SE team) about major decisions, which might be something rather novel for this site. In short, our personalities and approach to modding seems to mesh quite well, which has made the work much easier. An election _might_ severely upset this fine balance, which causes me some angst. Of course, an election _will_ come sooner or later, and I hope the electorate takes their task seriously.

Comment: You know, one does not vote to get a badge...

Comment: @AsafKaragila, the main thing that MSE is missing is a Dictator For Life. The wife of Old John is up for this in England, it is just a matter of time before the entire world...

Comment: Why do you want to get the Caucas badge?

Comment: @حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع: Perhaps because of the striking similarity to the word Couscous; or perhaps because people like having badges, and much like Pokemon, they want to have them all.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Right. The only reason someone would want to be a moderator is because that way they can get the `sheriff` badge.

Comment: @Thmas: Only the OP specifically mentioned Caucus.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Sorry, I was trying to be funny.

Comment: @Thomas: Don't you know that anything you write on the internet without a smiley face will be taken seriously?

Comment: I do see a point in checks and balances, but the obvious problem with reelections is that most moderation activity is invisible to most users and the secrecy is needed to work effectively. On the other hand, I feel uncomfortable with arguments that could come from James R. Clapper...

Comment: @AsafKaragila: It is late, but here it is: :)

Comment: @Michael: Better a Clapper than having the clap. I think. Maybe?

Comment: @Asaf `@Thmas: Only ` see what you get from not using tab completion for notify?! :-) [Sorry for the noise.]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99515/222372) on metaSE:

> The community team periodically looks at the work load on graduated sites and will reach out to the moderation team if it looks like more help might be needed. Broadly, it's up to the moderation teams to indicate whether they need additional hands, and how many sets of hands would be ideal.
>
> Although we'll reach out to moderators on the anniversary of their last election, just to see how they're doing, elections do not *always* take place at the same time every year. Sometimes a year can even go by without any election at all. Most elections are scheduled as a result of moderators reaching out to Stack Exchange to ask for additional help.